# Send arraylist to array to check if puzzle is solvable

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to send my Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Tile> myList = new ArrayList<Tile>();
```

that after:

```
public void shuffleBoard() {
    Collections.shuffle(myList); 

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 

    }

    switch (SIZE) {

    case 0:
        moveEmptyTile(Direction.UP);

    case 1:
        moveEmptyTile(Direction.DOWN);

    case 2:
        moveEmptyTile(Direction.LEFT);

    case 3:
        moveEmptyTile(Direction.RIGHT);
    }
```

Looks like this:

```
[[ 05 ], [ 12 ], [ ** ], [ 08 ], [ 02 ], [ 03 ], [ 01 ], [ 10 ], [ 04 ], [ 11 ], [ 07 ], [ 15 ], [ 13 ], [ 09 ], [ 06 ], [ 14 ]]
```

This I want to send to an array, so I can check if the board is solvable by this code:

```
 public static boolean isSolvable(int[] state){

    //prepare the mapping from each tile to its position
    int[] positions = new int[16];
    for(int i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
        positions[state[i]] = (i+1)%16;
    }

    //check whether this is an even or odd state
    int row = (positions[0]-1)/4;
    int col = (positions[0]-1)-row*4;
    boolean isEvenState = positions[0] == 0 || row % 2 == col %2;

    //count the even cycles
    int evenCount = 0;
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[16];
    for(int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
        if(visited[i]) 
            continue; 
        //a new cycle starts at i. Count its length..
        int cycleLength = 0;
        int nextTile = i;
        while(!visited[nextTile]){
            cycleLength++;
            visited[nextTile] = true;
            nextTile = positions[nextTile];
        }
        if(cycleLength % 2 == 0)
            evenCount++;
    }
    return isEvenState == (evenCount % 2 == 0);
```

So I want to convert my `Arraylist` to an `Array`, and return that as 
`int[] state` to `isSolvable(int[] state)` so that can check if my puzzle is solvable.

It is probably something stupid simple, but my head is jelly after trying
to search this forum for a solution.

My Tile class:

```
public class Tile {
private int value;
private static int maxValue = 15;
private static int minValue = 0;


public Tile(int value) {
    setValue(value);

}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    if (value <= maxValue)
        this.value = value;
    else if (value > maxValue)
        System.err.print("To high");
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (getValue() == minValue) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (this.isEmpty() == true)  {
        return "[ ** ]";
    }
    if (this.value < 10) {
        return "[ 0" + value + " ]"; 
    }
    else { 
        return "[ " + value + " ]";
    }
}
```

}

Sincerely yours.

Comment: How can a `Tile` (whatever this is) be converted to an `int`?

Comment: The  `Tile` is an `int` that has been sent to an `toString`.
If I cant to as described above, then I simply has to redo some of my code and use an `array` instead of an `arraylist`, as much as i get it.

Comment: No. A `Tile` is a `Tile` and an `int` is an `int`. A `Tile` is possibly a class that you declared yourself. This declaration is an important part of your question, so please show that code also!

Comment: Question updated with code

Comment: The question remains: How can a `Tile` be converted to an `int`? Or better: What `int` value does a `Tile` represent? Maybe you simply want to extract the `int` field `value`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I said my head is jelly ;-). Never thought of that.
If you can point me into the right direction, I would be pleased. And thank you.

Comment: No reason for excuse. :-) We are here to help, but sometimes we don't know excatly what askers want. So we have to ask some clarification questions. With showing your class `Tile` your question became clear. I gave you an answer.

Comment: Something different: The wording "send an array list" or "send to an array" is wrong or at least confusing. In a very general OOP speaking we say that we _send a message to an object_, which very simply is _calling a method on an object_. But this has nothing to do with your requirement. You simply wanted to _convert_ one data structure into another (here a `List<Tile>` into an `int[]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to build up an `int` array with a loop while converting each `Tile` into an `int` (I guess you want to extract the `value` field):

```
int size = myList.size();
int[] values = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    values[i] = myList.get(i).getValue();
}
```

Now you can call your method as simple as that:

```
boolean solveable = isSolvable(values);
```

With Java 8 (and later) you can simplify the array creating code using streams:

```
int[] values = myList.stream().mapToInt(Tile::getValue).toArray();
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks again.